# Level 2: "Four clever characters"

Tags: untrusted

Obviously, I found out my own solution to level 2 and even finished the whole game. What is constantly puzzling me, is the hint from the level description:

```
  Well, it looks like they're on to us. The path isn't as
  clear as I thought it'd be. But no matter - four clever
  characters should be enough to erase all their tricks.
```

The hint **specifically mentions four characters**

Did someone solve it by using only 4 characters? because my solution looks like this:

> var player = map.getPlayer();
>
>
>        map.placeObject(player.getX()+2, player.getY(), 'exit');

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are the four characters you're looking for

> /*  */

The hint was very specific about "*erasing* all their tricks"

Comment: oh, snap! This did hurt :)

Comment: That never occurred to me but it's awesome.

Comment: @PavelJanicek Don't beat yourself over it - there really is no right answer here, and half the fun of the game is to work out ways to solve a level in ways the designers never intended for them to be solved. My personal favourite is when I beat level 13 using a D-pad instead of a pathfinding algorithm - http://i.imgur.com/ifWM0ei.png

Comment: @PrivatePansy I was kinda hoping for a level that would subvert such tricks :-)

Comment: I used six: `if(0){  }`

Comment: @JohnDvorak Isn't that like literally impossible given the game is letting you run arbitrary JavaScript.